# Regex to allow Strings starting with a letter and not having a specific set of characters

Tags: regex

I need a regex that ensures two things -

1. My string must start with a letter. The letter can be small or capital.
2. The string must not contain certain specified characters.

Since there are two conditions involved, I tried designing my regex with the positive lookahead operator in regex (?=).

My regex for the String is

```
(?=^[a-zA-Z]$)(?=.[^"/',?%$@!#%^&+=|{}<>])
```

Where the first condition is to ensure that my string starts with a letter and the second condition is to ensure that the characters defined in the second condition are blocked. It still doesn't work for me. What am I missing? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Hi! Akhil, I see you're new here, so welcome! first of all you should ensure you scape the special characters by adding a backslash, for instance: \/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why having two conditions make you think that you should use lookaheads. In this case, 2 character classes should do:

```
^[a-zA-Z][^"\/',?%$@!#%^&*+=|{}<>]*$
```

The first character class matches the start (only letters), and the second matches the rest (no symbols).

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems:

- your first lookahead asserts that the string is only one character
  long (because of the `$` at the end); and
- the second lookahead only asserts that the second character is not one of the blocked ones (because you have no quantifier after the character class).

This would work better:

```
(?=^[a-zA-Z])(?=[^"/',?%$@!#%^&+=\`|{}<>]+$)
```

Note that since `[a-zA-Z]` is not part of the blocked group, you don't need the `.` to skip the first character in the second lookahead.